# How can I list the nodes for which a Boolean value is FALSE or NULL?

Tags: views, 9

On Drupal 9 I have a content type (Article), which has a not required Boolean field, *Need Further Review*.
Its values are `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NULL`, where the latter is used when the node doesn't have yet a value for the field.

There is a view for that content type, with an exposed filter for that field. The filter options are *Any*, *True*, and *False*.

How can I list the nodes for which the field value is `FALSE` or `NULL`?

Comment: Can't you just use the NOT operator with the filter so that the filter is "NOT TRUE"?

Comment: NOT TRUE list FALST AND NULL
BUT
NOT FALSE list TRUE AND NULL - this not work also